# Can my custom InputStream and outputStream objects work in a C# HTTP program?

Tags: c#, java, inputstream, outputstream

I have been referring to an open source HTTP proxy project written in java in order to implement my own proxy in C#; However there are some classes that i could not find their equivalent in .Net such as InputStream and OutputStream. I simply implemented my own classes by just deriving from the Stream class but i wonder if this will make my system able to run. Here are the classes:

```
     public class InputStream:Stream
     {
        public InputStream(NetworkStream networkStream)
        { }
        public InputStream(long Capacity)
        {
            this.SetLength(Capacity);
        }
        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

       public override bool CanSeek
       {
          get { return true; }
       }

       public override bool CanWrite
       {
           get { return false; }
       }

      public override void Flush()
      {
          throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not supported by   InputStream");
      }

      public override long Length
      {
           get { return this.Length; }
      }

      public override long Position
      {
          get
          {
            return this.Position;
           }
          set
          {
            this.Position = value;
          }
      }

      public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
      {
          return this.Read(buffer, offset, count);
      }

      public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
      {
          return this.Seek(offset, origin);
      }

      public override void SetLength(long value)
      {
           this.SetLength(value);
      }

      public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
      {
        throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not supported by InputStream");
      }
   }
```

The InputStream and OutputStream objects should act as networkStream objects except that the InputStream should only support read operation whereas the OuputStream should only support the write operation! I wonder if this is the good way of implementing two different networkStream objects in which one supports writing and the other supports reading!

Answer (score 1):

No, your code won't work. You're not doing anything with the stream that's passed to your constructor, and all your "supported" members just call themselves recursively, leading to a `StackOverflowException`.

You could delegate calls to the `NetworkStream` you're passed in, but it's hard to see what benefit that will really give you.

Just use the same `NetworkStream` for both the input stream and the output stream in your proxy code - you probably won't need to write your own class deriving from `Stream`.

Comment: If i use an output stream as a networkStream i will not be able to write to it (NetworkStream) since it does not support write operation!

Comment: @Xris: I don't follow, I'm afraid... it's really not clear what your other code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Calling any of your current methods will result in a StackOverflowException (assuming no tail-call optimisations!).

I presume your code should be delegating to equivalent methods on your passed NetworkStream object, rather than calling themselves.